# How to call an Odoo Controller function from JS file

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

i set a keyDown from JS file call a function in Py file

this is my JS file

```
_onKeydown_searchText: function () {
    var self = this;
    var search = {};
    search.Input = self.$('#text_input').val().trim();
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && search.Input) {
        return this._rpc({
        route: '/some/route',
        params: { search: search.Input }
        }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        self._result = data;
        })
    }
},
```

and this is my Py fucntion

```
@http.route('/some/route/', website=True, auth='public', csrf=False)
    def get_data(self, **kw):
        print(kw)
        condition = kw['search']
        sql = """
            select name from res_partner where phone = '%s' or email = '%s'
        """ % (condition, condition)
        http.request.cr.execute(sql)
        result = http.request.cr.fetchall() or []
        data = []
        list(data)
        for x in result:
            temp = ''.join(x)
            data.append(temp)
        return http.request.render("search_vip_route.get_data", {
            'data': data
        })
```

but i got this error :
**/some/route: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'**
Anyone can help me fix this

Answer (score 3):

lê chang

You can send the value from **JSON-RPC** into your **Json controller**

**Js File**:

```
var ajax = require('web.ajax');
ajax.jsonRpc("/custom/url", 'call', {'Your Key': Your Value}).then(function(data) {
if (data) {
    // Code
} else {
   // Code
}});
```

**Py File**: Get the data from the post like this.

```
@http.route(['/custom/url'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
def custom_cotroller(self, **post):
    get_data = post.get('Your Key')
    # Your Customise Code
```