# Pass data from Controller to JS in Odoo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-14

How can you pass data from a controller to JS. I'm trying to set the mindate on a date picker based on information in the controller qcontext. I've hacked together a solution of rendering the data in an empty span tag and reading it from the span tag through JS... But I'm hoping there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `json` controller from the `RPC-Call`.
Check this solution [Call Json Controller][1]

This is the same concept from there you can modify with the requirement with pass the data and perform same.
[1]: [How to call an Odoo Controller function from JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655012/how-to-call-an-odoo-controller-function-from-js-file/63657922#63657922)

Comment: You've made me think more about my question. I think it might be a case that I need to spend more time to find out the most efficient way to manage this. To give more context to the questions:    
- I have some items in the eCommerce Web Shop
- Each item has a different lead time
- All items are to be delivered at the same time
- I need to look at each items lead time, find the longest and then supply that as a date delta from today to the mindate property of the datepicker
- I have this working as stated using an empty span tag, just to hold that mindate value

Comment: I will accept your answer though, as it has given me a good steer on how to tackle this issue. I just need to work out how to get the order items information into this json route method. Thanks a million @dipen-shah

Comment: @Lazypaddy It depends on which level you have to achieve this, I mean to get the order information. So based on that we'll suggest best for you.